# How to integrate a CMS and a RESTful API with LDAP/AD?

Tags: rest, amazon-web-services, active-directory, ldap

So here's how it needs to work. The client has a requirement to build a CMS with a particular open source CMS. Users will login and will be authenticated via either Active Directory or LDAP. There are plugins that I can use, and have tested, that accomplishes this.

Here's the challenging part. We also need to build some custom components, that will be part of that CMS, that will make calls to a RESTful API, which we also have to build. That API must authenticate those already logged in users on both a group and user level.

What is the best path to pursue to integrate all three pieces of this puzzle?

Comment: Hi, this is a pretty broad question. Have you tried anything yet? Or maybe have a suggestion on how to accomplish this?

Comment: I know that LDAP is a stateful protocol, so there's no token. I don't know how I'd then authenticate against an API. How would the API know what user/group the request is coming from? I did set up an LDAP server, have authenticated agains that, but don't know where to go after that, for that reason.

Comment: With AD, I don't know much about it. Is there a token I get? Do I pass some sort of token to an API? I'm looking for an answer, somewhere along the lines of, "you need to authenticate against AD, obtain a token, then include the token with requests to an API that integrates with AD..." Its a broad question and I'm looking for a broad answer, or at least just a pointer in a particular direction.